# Anyone have issues with a MySQL 5.1 to 5.5 in-place Upgrade in Production?

Tags: mysql, redhat, mysql5

We are about to upgrade our MySQL boxes from 5.1 to 5.5 and because of the size, would prefer to do this as an in-place upgrade.
Are there any issues with this?  From my research, I noticed that the MySQL manuals for 5.0 and 5.1 mention that they are ok, but the 5.5 manual recommends a dump/restore.
I've seen on blogs, [for instance](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/red-hat-31/centos-5-4-upgrading-from-mysql-5-0-to-5-5-safest-way-830988/#post4091518), vague responses of "I've had problems..." but nothing specific.

Has anyone done this and have had success or failure?  For reference, I'm on RH 5.
Thanks!
-Dave

(Note: Not sure if this belongs here or DB Admins but I see more similar questions here )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a MySQL DBA, **I have never trusted mysql_upgrade**. The Achilles' heel of moving data from one release of MySQL to a higher release of MySQL is the risk of messing up the tables in the mysql schema. The best thing you can do is dump all databases except information_schema database (mysqldump ignores that by default) and the mysql database.

How can one safely migrate the MySQL user permissions from an old mysql instance to a new one ???

- [I addressed this in another ServerFault question I answered just four days ago](https://serverfault.com/questions/312818/should-i-backup-and-restore-the-mysql-database/312856#312856)
- [I also addressed this in the DBA StackExchange 4 weeks ago](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4114/restoring-an-old-backup-to-latest-mysql-release/4127#4127)
- [I even give instructions on how to dump grants and data separately](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-optimize-a-mysqldump-of-a-large-database/2227#2227)

I have done that way for years and I would never recommend otherwise.

Give it a Try !!!